# Use non-JSON format for Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

I'm using JAX-RS (with RESTEasy) and the latest version of Jackson for marshaling objects in JSON. I simply specify a return content type to be `application/json`, for example, and my object is converted to JSON. I can use Jackson annotations to tweak which properties are serialized, how they are named, etc.

I have a custom text-based Foo format `text/foo` (for the sake of discussion) that is similar to JSON but different, especially in the way that objects and properties are delimited. I want to be able to specify `text/foo` as a return content type and have my object automatically serialized to the Foo format. I want my marshaling library to be independent of the JAX-RS implementation.

My first thought was to leverage Jackson somehow, so that I could make use of Jackson's annotations for property names, etc. That way some object that had been configured for JSON using Jackson would, if I changed the content type to `text/foo`, be serialized to the Foo format yet still use the property names indicated by the Jackson annotations.

Jackson turns out to be pretty complex, with various APIs, and it's not obvious where to start.

- Is it possible to leverage Jackson to serialize objects to a non-JSON format?
- Which Jackson API (tree model, streaming API, or databinding) should I use?
- Is there some existing non-JSON Jackson library that would serve as an example to help me get started?
- Is using Jackson in this way simply more trouble than it's worth, and should I instead just write JAX-RS `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` implementations, skipping Jackson altogether? (I hesitate to go down this road, because I would have to write all the reflection logic from scratch, write my own annotations for specifying property name changes etc., and forgo all the type plugin infrastructure of Jackson.)

Comment: You should take a look at the [jackson-dataformats-text](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text) project. This supports Jackson to YAML, CSV etc... You could perhaps use this as a starting point to implement your own format.

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks for the reference, but ... yeah, we found that right away in a Google search. It looks promising but when you get into it it's not useful for a new format that is richer than JSON.

Comment: @GarretWilson Can you give more details on your custom format? You seem to have done your research, so without details it'd be hard to decide where to start.

Comment: @Sheepy, the format is SURF: https://urf.io/surf/

Comment: @GarretWilson I've check SURF.  It has a much richer expression than JSON, so I don't think you can just plug a layer on top of Jackson.  It's like changing the wheels of a train to make it run like a car, but a train is not a car and you're going to end up with lots of difficulties.  You'd end up expanding / rewriting many part of Jackson.

Comment: @Sheepy, thanks for the response and for taking the time to look into this. Magno came to the same conclusion after the research he did (see separate answer). I've pretty much decided we'll write all the marshaling from scratch, which means we'll have to build our own reflection logic, annotations, etc. But we're going to create a separate, reusable library for that so people don't have to reinvent the wheel to marshal objects using other formats.

Answer (score 1):

**Advantages on Jackson API**

- Is one of the fastest libraries available to handle with JSON files.
- Has a more extensive annotation support, and even accepts annotations from other APIs like JAXB.
- Has a better integration with JAX-RS.

**Streaming (core)**

*This is the core of Jackson, it's where the parser/serializer stays, handling with streaming of the input/output data.*

- This is the fastest way available for parsing/serializing data.
- Not the most convenient way to process JSON content.

  - The content must be processed in exact same order as input/output to work, i.e., no random access.
  - More used by middleware and frameworks, but not very common for applications.

This is the API that we must to implement to have a completely functional version of Jackson that supports the data format that we want. It is also the only API implemented by other data formats like XML, Java Properties, YAML, and others.

**DataBinding and TreeModel will be automatically supported after implementing this API.**

GSON was also studied along with Jackson, but due its similarity to Jackson and its lack in the performance, Jackson is the main subject for this report.

*The difference of performance is due to the way that those APIs handle with data, Jackson was using streams at first, which is a fast low-level approach, and it made of Jackson the fastest API to handle with JSON when it was launched.*

*And although GSON has also started using this approach to handle with data, Jackson is still the fastest API according to benchmark tests that may be found on the section on references.*

**TreeModel**

*This is the part of the api that provides a mutable in-memory tree representation of a JSON document.*

This API is the most flexible when handling with some data format similar to XML.

**DataBinding**

*This is the part of the api that converts JSON to and from POJOs based either on property accessor conventions or annotations.*

The most convenient way to process JSON content.
It allows conversion between JSON data and JAVA objects.
Similar to TreeModel, but use Java objects instead of a node-based model.

This API is the most used in terms of applications

---

**Notes about Jackson Streaming Implementation**

As this is the only API that we need to implement, we will give more attention to this one.

The Implementation for Streaming API uses what's called `JsonToken` to identify the upcoming JSON objects coming in the stream, i.e., the input/output data.

The `JsonToken` enum has the following definitions:

```
NOT_AVAILABLE(null), 
START_OBJECT("{"), 
END_OBJECT("}"), 
START_ARRAY("["), 
END_ARRAY("]"), 
FIELD_NAME(null), 
VALUE_STRING(null), 
VALUE_NUMBER_INT(null), 
VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT(null), 
VALUE_TRUE("true"), 
VALUE_FALSE("false"), 
VALUE_NULL("null")
```

These tokens can be retrieved by what's called `ReadContext`. The `ReadContext` has some constants to define its own type.

Constants used internally to represent a `JsonStreamContext` type.

```
protected final static int TYPE_ROOT = 0; // Means the root element.
protected final static int TYPE_ARRAY = 1; // Means the array elements.
protected final static int TYPE_OBJECT = 2; // Means the JSON object elements.
```

Snippet of the constructor methods of ReadContext for the Java Properties data format.

```
JPropReadContext extends JsonStreamContext {
    // Static factory method used to create the JPropReadContext instance.
    public static JPropReadContext create(JPropNode root) {
        if (root.isArray()) { // can this ever occur?
                return new ArrayContext(null, root);
        }
        return new ObjectContext(null, root);
    }
    …
    ArrayContext extends JPropReadContext {
        // Constructor for ArrayContext.
        public ArrayContext(JPropReadContext p, JPropNode arrayNode) {
            super(JsonStreamContext.TYPE_ARRAY, p, arrayNode);
            _contents = arrayNode.arrayContents();
            _state = STATE_START;
        }
        …
    }
    …
    ObjectContext extends JPropReadContext {
        // Constructor for ObjectContext.
        public ObjectContext(JPropReadContext p, JPropNode objectNode) {
            super(JsonStreamContext.TYPE_OBJECT, p, objectNode);
            _contents = objectNode.objectContents();
            _state = STATE_START;
        }
        …
    }
    …
}
```

`JPropReadContext` merely extends `JsonStreamContext`, so it needs to pass a constant from `JsonStreamContext` to it, indicating the type of the context, if it's a root, an array or an object. The constant is a simply int value, so no problem until that.

Here's the same information but now for the XML data format.

```
…
// Static factory method used to create the XmlReadContext instance of type ROOT.
public static XmlReadContext createRootContext(int lineNr, int colNr) {
    return new XmlReadContext(null, TYPE_ROOT, lineNr, colNr);
}

// Static factory method used to create the XmlReadContext instance of type ARRAY.
public final XmlReadContext createChildArrayContext(int lineNr, int colNr) {
    XmlReadContext ctxt = _child;       
    if (ctxt == null) {
        _child = ctxt = new XmlReadContext(this, TYPE_ARRAY, lineNr, colNr);
        return ctxt;
    }
    ctxt.reset(TYPE_ARRAY, lineNr, colNr);
    return ctxt;
}

// Static factory method used to create the XmlReadContext instance of type OBJECT.
public final XmlReadContext createChildObjectContext(int lineNr, int colNr) {
    XmlReadContext ctxt = _child;
    if (ctxt == null) {
        _child = ctxt = new XmlReadContext(this, TYPE_OBJECT, lineNr, colNr);
        return ctxt;
    }
    ctxt.reset(TYPE_OBJECT, lineNr, colNr);
    return ctxt;
}
…
```

What the implementations for other data formats for Jackson do is simply use these constants and the `JsonToken`    as if their format was a Json instance, in other words, it fakes their own format to make it look like a Json instance for Jackson, which is not a clean way. For example, they can make use of `TYPE_OBJECT` to represent something like `<element>value<element>` or `property = "string containing the value of the property."`.

This works for formats that have the same/less amount of features than Json, because every feature can be implemented, but it's impossible for data formats that have more features than that.

---

This report was made for GlobalMentor Inc., as part of https://globalmentor.atlassian.net/browse/URF-33, where we try to implement the support for the [SURF data format](https://urf.io/surf/) in Jackson.